# synchronising multiple macs... where to start?

Tags: data-synchronization

I am wanting to do some pretty serious mac synchronisation...
I want to know how far I can go in terms of getting my two macs to be always identical to one another. Unfortunately files are just not enough. I want like system images of one exother, but ongoing

Where do I begin?